# Does LinqPad support latest Odata libraries?

Tags: odata, linqpad

Does Linqpad use OData (WCF Data services) client library to generate the proxy that'll call the Data service OR does it use plain http/REST?  Since it was getting strongly typed context, which can be used for the queries, I assume its using a proxy?
If its the former, is there a way to update the OData client library to be used by Linqpad?

Answer (score 1):

LINQPad uses EntityClassGenerator in System.Data.Services.Design to generate the client proxy classes. This class is a standard part of the .NET Framework - I'm not aware of an updated OData client library... is there one?

**Edit:** LINQPad now supports OData 5 (from version 4.42.06).

Comment: One difference I just noticed is that unlike the VS2010 service ref generated types, the LINQPad types do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so you can't add them to a DataContextCollection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373844.aspx

Comment: Also, LINQPad types uses `Collection` for navigation properties, where as service ref-generated types use DataContextCollection.

Comment: The latest WCF Data Service 5.0 supports `Any\All` LINQ queries against OData: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2011/05/31/any-all-support-in-wcf-data-services.aspx   My service supports this if I send the query via a url, but using Linq syntax, LINQPad will throw a "Any is not supported" exception.